# How do I avoid StaleElementException after WebElement.click() for an ajax button?

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-chromedriver

I have a page which has a small form with one input field and a submit button. **The submit button is AJAX!** When I click it, it submits the input value to the server which either validates it as acceptable and loads a new page, or else finds a problem and adds a feedback error label.

I have written the following selenium code to test this functionality:

```
WebDriverWait waiter = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement inputField = waiter.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("inputField")));
inputField.sendKeys("Test input");

WebElement submitInput = waiter.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("submitInput")));
submitInput.click();

WebElement feedback = waiter.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("feedback")));
Assert.assertTrue("Feedback not was not empty, but was: " + feedback.getText(), feedback.getText().isEmpty());
```

The problem is that `submitInput.click()` completes and returns straight away if the new page is loaded via an event as per: [the selenium docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html), so the call to retrieve by "feedback" works fine, and I can see through debugging that it gets the element correctly, however I get a `StaleElementException` when I call `feedback.getText()`, because the page has since refreshed in the background.

How can I get the test to pass without:

1. Adding Thread.sleep().
2. Adding a `StaleElementException` catch to refetch the element.

*Note*: The above test works when the input is invalid because the page is not refreshed, but not when the input is valid.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT: Please note this is not a problem with polling the page until an element appears, but is a problem with detecting whether `submitInput.click()` loads a new page or adds text to an existing label.**

**EDIT 2: To illustrate the problem I have compiled a time logged run-through interleaving the test and server logs:**

```
16:34:48,589 - TEST   - Navigating to page.
16:34:48,605 - SERVER - Page request started.
16:34:48,631 - SERVER - Page request ended.
16:34:49,050 - TEST   - Typing test input.
16:34:49,456 - TEST   - Clicking button.
16:34:49,519 - SERVER - Received click event.
16:34:49,529 - SERVER - Responding with redirect.
16:34:49,556 - TEST   - Finding feedback by id.
16:34:49,560 - SERVER - Page request started.
16:34:49,581 - SERVER - Page request ended.
16:34:49,775 - TEST   - Test threw exception.
```

You can see that the server receives the click event just over half a second after it's sent from the test. It immediately responds with (in this case) a redirect command. The test has meanwhile [continued in the background as per the docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) due to the click being an AJAX event, and this results in (as you can see) the test retrieving the feedback 0.004 seconds before the server receives a new page request. By the time `feedback.getText()` has been parsed and sent to ChromeDriver, the server has already responded with a new page, and therefore this function returns the stale exception.

The key point really is that I can fix this fine using `Thread.sleep(1000)`, but this is far from ideal; firstly because there may be occasions where the server takes longer than half a second to parse the AJAX and return a result, and this makes the tests non-deterministic, and secondly because these times soon stack up and waste time, usually unnecessarily when only a few milliseconds was required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution in the end for anyone who has a similar problem (which was two different problems, 1 - detecting an AJAX controlled page change, and 2 - detecting an AJAX controlled element change), was

step 1: Create a few functions to track page changes through jQuery (jQuery is used on all pages, so the script executes fine):

```
private void updateLastChange()
{
    driver.executeScript("$('html').data('CHANGED_PAGE', false)");
}

public boolean pageChanged()
{
    Object script = driver.executeScript("return $('html').data('CHANGED_PAGE');");
    Boolean changed = (Boolean)script;
    if(changed == null)
    {
        updateLastChange();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I can then simply call `pageChanged()` to detect a page change.

step 2: to create an anonymous class which implements `ExpectedCondition<Boolean>`.

Using my example from above where the problem was that feedback is non-deterministic regarding when it will be ready, I changed the bottom two lines from the code in the question to:

```
WebDriverWait waiter = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5, 200);
waiter.ignoring(AssertionFailedError.class);
waiter.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
waiter.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>()
{
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver input)
    {
        WebElement feedback = input.findElement(By.id("feedback"));
        Assert.assertTrue("Feedback not was not empty, but was: " + feedback.getText(), feedback.getText().isEmpty());            
        return true;
    }
});
```

This way, it polls the page every 200 milliseconds for 5 seconds ignoring assertion exceptions and stale element exceptions. The only way it passes is if the `return true;` line is reached before the 5 seconds has run out. I'm currently thinking about how to make this neater but it works great, is faster than simply sleeping, and succeeds early (when possible) due to the polling.

Comment: This isn't a good solution for testers who cannot edit source code.  Also, even though the page changed , it does not ensure that the element exists on the page.  I think eugenes answer below is far more reliable.

Comment: @djangofan, which source code are you talking about? Surely a tester can edit the source code of the tests they are writing, that's the only edit being made... I do agree it's not a good solution though, when using Selenium we should always strive to test from a users perspective, and the user doesn't care whether the page changed or not, they only care about the data being displayed to them. I have since removed the pageChanged method because it's not a valuable testing method, and makes the tests more likely to be brittle.

Comment: when I said 'source code', I meant that QA and DEV are usually separate and DEV writes code for the application that QA does not have access to.

Comment: If you have removed pageChanged(), do you have an alternative solution?

Comment: Yes @frederik-de-mets, we now use the [PageObject pattern](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) in combination with the FindBy annotation, and the [PageFactory](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) helper class, supplying an AjaxElementLocatorFactory. Now, selenium takes care of polling for my elements until a supplied timeout. I can use the pre-made ExpectedConditions class to help poll for specific conditions, or even create my own for special cases. I would strongly recommend it. :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can grasp the AjaxElementLocatorFactory. I'm already using PageObjects.

Answer (score 2):

i would actually act in some other way to resolve this issue. 
I would use some js to overcome  `StaleElementException` +++ fluent wait +++ css selectors instead of xpaths.
1) **fluent wait** method. it returns you actual (located) web element:

```
public WebElement fluentWait(final By locator){
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

    WebElement foo = wait.until(
        new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return driver.findElement(locator);
            }
        }
    );
    return  foo;
};
```

about fluent wait you can get [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html)  and [here](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium-support/2.9.0/selenium-support-2.9.0-sources.jar!/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.java?format=ok)

2) String cssSelectorInputField = "[id='inputField']" 
   String cssSelectorSubmitInput = "[id='submitInput']" 
   String cssSelectorFeedback = "[id='feedback']"

3) now i give some jsMethods templates (that i use for my automation that prolly can be useful for you)

```
public String jsGetText(String cssSelector){

  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\""+cssSelector+"\");");
        stringBuilder.append("return x.text().toString();")       ;


       String res= (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
return res;
}

public String jsGetColor(String css){

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x=$(\'"+css+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("return x.css('color')");
        String res= (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
        return res;

    }

public void jsClickOnElement(String css){

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.append("var x = $(\'"+css+"\');");
        stringBuilder.append("x.click();");
        js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());

}
```

4) so final steps be something like:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelectorInputField)).sendKeys("Test input");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssSelectorSubmitInput)).click();
//or jsClickOnElement(cssSelectorSubmitInput);
WebElement feedBack =fluentWait(cssSelectorFeedback);
String textForVerifying=feedBack.getText().trim();
//or String textForVerifying= jsGetText(cssSelectorFeedback);
Assert.assertTrue(textForVerifying.equals("..blablablab..."));
```

hope this works for you now)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I'm using WebDriverWait which extends FluentWait<WebDriver>, and basically does all that initialisation for me which you showed in point 1. The real problem is that the feedback label already exists on the page, but is hidden. Therefore it is capturing this element before the ajax event has done a round trip to the server, but using it after the page has changed. I'll modify the question to make this clearer.

Comment: try to be stick to the element (e.g. button, but not feedback with fluent wait). And then get text with jsMehtod as I've described. js approach should always work.

Comment: I've tried the javascript method, but it still doesn't block so I'm getting an element on one page, but by the time I use it the page has refreshed in the background, I've also tried putting FluentWaits on the different `findElement()` methods including all of them, but to no avail, I'm re-editing my question to hopefully show better what the problem is.

Comment: i see the point. Speaking about fluent wait usage, it better use it instead of driver.findElement(blablabla)
i mean that call driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(..blabla..)) and call fluendWait(By.cssSelector(....blablabla...)) are totally equivalent.

Comment: @Jamey - I don't see how using FluentWait could possibly fail.  In my experience it always works.  As long as you are handling all the error conditions that are possibly thrown, they can be handled by a loop.   When you say "i've tried", I would say try harder.  Just look at the exception you are getting and handle it with a .ignoring method.

Comment: @djangofan My final solution, which is now used extensively across the project, actually works in a very similar way to `FluentWait`. The secret was that I was relying on the element returned after the fluent wait, but I actually needed to do all the testing for the element in the apply method of the `Function` I pass to `wait.until()`. This way once the `fluentWait()` method has returned, I am guaranteed to have found the element and successfully run my assertions on its state.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget about such methods as

```
input.findElements(By.xpath("//xpath")).size() > 0


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath")).isDisplayed()

public bool IsElementPresent(By selector)
{
    return driver.FindElements(selector).Any();
}
```

for verifying element existence on the page. they can also be quite helpful. But pay attention to locators you find (verify in firebug that all elements you located properly)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how this can be done in Java, nor am I sure I understood the scenario correctly, but I'll make an attempt. Its in Ruby btw...

```
 @wait.until { @driver.find_element(:id,"feedback") }
 assert "true","Feedback was not empty but was #{@driver.find_element(:id,\"feedback\").text}"
```

What I am basically trying to do is NOT use the web-element 'feedback' that was found/presence-located, in the line above the assert. Instead I made the webdriver find the element again and then performed some action(get text) on it.

**EDIT**

---

```
@wait.until { alert_text = @driver.find_element(:id,"feedback").text }
assert_match "expected text","#{alert_text}","Feedback is not empty and expected"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion it's an improvement, however the calls to `find_element` and `text` are different requests, i.e. `find_element` performs a webdriver request to get the element, but `text` performs a separate request to get the text from that element (the text is not returned from results of `find_element`). This means that potentially the page could still update in the background between requests. I just tried it and it did...

Comment: Still has the same problem, (in Java anyway). Thanks though, I found a solution which is good enough.